Display live iPhone screen in Keynote slide
Keynote only shows the internal camera as a source for live video. Is there an app that can make the iPhone mirrored screen look like it's a camera? Or is there another way to make this work? I've done various searches and the only thing I could find is iDemo. That app is 14 years old and I think it ran on a jailbroken iPhone.

No need to use a third-party app, Keynote has this functionality. You will need another device from which you can add a new live video source.
When selecting the source, you have the option to add a new source (at the top-right corner of the list). You then just have to select an iPhone from the list (or an iPad, as in the example).


Once you confirm the addition of the source, its screen (if it's an iPhone or iPad) will be broadcasted live.

